# Connection refused Error displayed Android studio connect with Sql Server

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple CRUD using Android Studio with Sqlserver. When I add data into the database I got the error ConnectionRefusedError.
I have attached the code below what I tried so far. I have been trying to connect the database for 2 two days but it hasn't let me.

I add the jar file successfully 
jtds-1.2.7.jar

and I get the IP address of the SQL server and its port

[image]

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"


        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/course"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"

        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**java**

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText ed1,ed2;
        Button b1,b2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ed1 = findViewById(R.id.title);
            ed2 = findViewById(R.id.course);
            b1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            b2 = findViewById(R.id.v1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    insert();
                }
            });
        }

        public void insert() {
            try {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.84.2; databaseName=skill; port =0; user=sa; password=admin123";
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                PreparedStatement pst;
                String title = ed1.getText().toString();
                String description = ed2.getText().toString();
                pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into course(coursename,fee)values(?,?)");
                pst.setString(1, title);
                pst.setString(2, description);
                pst.executeUpdate();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                ed1.requestFocus();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Record Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConnectionRefused` error simply means that the host computer is refusing a connection on that port. Perhaps the port is blocked on the host's firewall? If you have access to the host, you can simply unblock the port. Please report back with what you find.

Comment: sir. i turnofff the firewall and tried sir but didn't work any code problem sir

Comment: @nishankishan glad to hear that! What was the problem?